# Disable NSParameterAssert in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, assert

I want to disable **NSParameterAssert** in the application

I am using **AFOAuth2Manager** using pod.So I cannot comment or delete the lines in this specific file.This file(**AFOAuth2Manager.m**) purely depend upon podfile

I want to disable the following lines in my project

**NSParameterAssert(url);**

**NSParameterAssert(clientID);**

**NSParameterAssert(secret);**

Please check the following code contain in **AFOAuth2Manager.m** file

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
 sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration
             clientID:(NSString *)clientID
               secret:(NSString *)secret {
    NSParameterAssert(url);
    NSParameterAssert(clientID);
    NSParameterAssert(secret);
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:configuration];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.serviceProviderIdentifier = [self.baseURL host];
    self.clientID = clientID;
    self.secret = secret;
    self.useHTTPBasicAuthentication = YES;
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    return self;
}
```

Could you please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?
"Assert" means if this condition is not met, this method will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it technically.

```rb
# Inject the target macro.
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "AFOAuth2Manager"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'NSParameterAssert'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This hook script will replace the original `NSParameterAssert` definition from `Foundation.framework` with `nil`, you could check this build settings in the `AFOAuth2Manager` target in `Pods` project after running `pod install`. Now Xcode starts to build that target with the predefined macros, this is really a hack way.

Let's talk about the macro `NSParameterAssert` usage, this macro is used to assert the required parameters when developing the libraries. It hopes the library caller passing a `nonnull` parameter to the current method, you (the caller) have the responsibility to check the nullability condition before calling the method.

So, the prefer way for you is this:

```c
if (url && clientID && secret) {
    AFOAuth2Manager *manager = [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url
                                                   sessionConfiguration:configuration
                                                               clientID:clientID
                                                                 secret:secret];
} else {
    # ...
}
```